# Implementing operator-> in a range adaptor's iterator class

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, range, adaptor

Let's consider a very basic range adaptor class which wraps around a range and iterates over every other element of the original range if you iterate over the adaptor.

```
for (const auto & e : everyOtherElement(originalRange))
```

When writing such a range adaptor class, one needs to write a corresponding iterator class for that adaptor to make it iterable and behave like desired.

Such an iterator class should implement everything required by the "concept" you want it to support, for example [`InputIterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/InputIterator). Among other things, we should implement `operator*` to return a reference to the represented element, as well as `operator->` such that `it->member` accesses members of that element.

I thought that it would be a good idea to simply "forward" these operators to the implementation of the underlying iterator the adaptor wraps around (let's forget about const-ness for a moment):

```
struct everyOtherElement {
    OriginalIterator b, e; // The begin and end we wrap around
    // ...
    struct iterator {
        OriginalIterator it;
        auto operator*() { return *it; }                  // <------
        auto operator->() { return it.operator->(); }     // <------
        // ...
    };
};
```

However, the `operator->` fails to compile if `OriginalIterator` is of pointer type, like for most `std::vector` implementations and of course raw arrays. Because such iterators are non-class types, it's not allowed to write `it.operator->()`.

How should I implement the `operator->` to make the iterator as transparent as possible? Should I implement `operator->` in terms of `operator*`, i.e. like just writing `(*it).m` instead of `it->m`. I guess this fails if some iterator implements them to mean different things... (Although that would be evil, wouldn't it? Or is that forbidden by the `InputIterator` concept?)

Is it a good idea to implement it as just returning the original iterator, since `operator->` is recursively applied automatically as long as returning a non-pointer?

```
        auto operator->() { return it; }
```

Comment: As I assume that there are templates involved, I would suggest just to use SFINAE/tag dispatch to select implementation depending if OriginalIterator is pointer or not.

Answer (score 1):

See standard iterator adapters specification, for instance [move_iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/move_iterator):

```
pointer     Iterator
```

they define `pointer` type as `Iterator` and indeed [return it](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/move_iterator/operator*) by operator `->`